# macro to insert user defined number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code which will add 7 columns every time a run it after every column that contains data from cell D3. is there a way to add a message box that will ask for the amount of lines that we want to add?

```
dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Range("D3").End(xlToRight).Column
'j is the last column
For k = j To 5 Step -1
Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(3, k + 6)).EntireColumn.Insert
Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, see code below with comments (with modification to the insert line)

*Assuming you are asking user for the number of columns to insert.*

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251811(v=office.15).aspx

```
Sub Wsh_AddColumnsFromUserInput()

Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim bCols As Byte

bCols = InputBox("How many columns do want to insert?", "Some tittle here")
Rem Set min & max
If bCols < 1 Then bCols = 1
If bCols > 7 Then bCols = 7

'j is the last column
j = ActiveSheet.Range("D3").End(xlToRight).Column

For k = j To 5 Step -1
    ActiveSheet.Columns(k).Resize(, bCols).EntireColumn.Insert
Next k

End Sub
```